# ChartJS fails to render one of the lines in cartesian chart following update after change to max Y axis label value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have encountered a problem while creating a manual Y axis limit selector for ChartJS, where in Firefox I am able to apply said change to the chart's options, update it and it'll crop the graph accordingly, no problems:

[Firefox Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2TnV.png)

As seen in the attached image, the behavior works as expected with the Y axis boundaries set to between 0 and 20. However, in Google Chrome, for this same graph, the second line becomes invisible, but I can still hover over points in it and interact with the "ghost line":

[Chrome Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56cTq.png)

The blue line has more uniform data, with the values varying between 0 and 2 mA in this graph. The green graph has values that vary between 0 and 5e+34 mA. That doesn't mean it should be a problem, though, as it works fine in Firefox and somehow, the lines are still "kinda there" in Chrome.

The following is how I am applying min/max changes:

```
if(chart.options.scales.yAxes.length <= 1)
        return;

    for(let i=1; i < chart.options.scales.yAxes.length; i++){
        if(chart.options.scales.yAxes[i].id == axisId){
            var limit = parseFloat(limitInput.value);
            if($(limitInput).attr("placeholder") === "Max"){
                if(!isNaN(limit)){
                    chart.options.scales.yAxes[i].ticks.max =  limit;
                } else {
                    delete chart.options.scales.yAxes[i].ticks.max;
                }
            } else {
                if(!isNaN(limit)) {
                    chart.options.scales.yAxes[i].ticks.min =  limit;
                } else { 
                    delete chart.options.scales.yAxes[i].ticks.min;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    chart.update();
```

As of now, I have tried updating with no animation and sync behavior, clearing the chart and rerendering with .render(), but to no avail. This code works with datasets that have values that are more even.

This problem persists as of ChartJS 2.9.3 and the latest versions of both Chromium and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue with the way Chrome renders and pixels going out of bounds, as presented [here](http://%20https://codepen.io/kurkle/pen/VwaXWwY) and in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/7776). There is no way of solving this properly without changing ChartJS code